# How to use background package multiple times

Tags: packages, backgrounds

how can I use background package to draw different backgrounds?

For example, this code

```
\usepackage[center,all]{background}
\SetBgContents{Wrote by Human - Wrote by Human - Wrote by Human - }
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{black!40}
\SetBgScale{1}
```

draws on each page a diagonal text (Wrote by Human - Wrote by Human - Wrote by Human - ). I would like to write more of these lines spaced vertically (on the diagonal).
Can somebody help me please?
Thank you anyway and have a nice day :)

Comment: Have a try with Tikz.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get multiple lines is to put the content you want in a table:

[image]

If you wish to change this on subsequenet pages you can redefine `\MyWatermark`.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[center,all]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{\MyWatermark}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgColor{red}
\SetBgScale{1}

\newcommand*{\MyWatermark}{%
    \Huge
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        Wrote by Human \\ 
        Wrote by Monkey \\ 
        Wrote by Human \\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\renewcommand*{\MyWatermark}{%
    \Huge
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        Wrote by Me \\ 
        Wrote by Monkey \\ 
        Wrote by Me \\
    \end{tabular}%
}
\lipsum[8-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Super, so I can simply insert a tabular in the argument of SetBgContents. Can you explain me why it is not working writing something like
```
SetBgContents{Wrote by Monkey\\ Wrote by Rock\\ Wrote by Monkey}
```
?

Comment: Probably is is using an \hbox instead of a \vbox.  Only \vbox (in its many varieties) can handle more than one line.